# Ignore SSL for MySQL in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I want to set up my database.yml (or wherever else is more appropriate) to ignore the SSL certificate when trying to connect to the database. I know this is bad practice but it is only a temporary thing that I need.

To give an example of what I'm trying to do, I want to mimic this SQL connection command:

```
mysql --ssl=0 -h 10.10.10.10 -u admincreds -p
```

I have tried putting each of the following parameters in the last line (sslca, sslkey, and sslcert) in my database.yml configuration as such:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  host: 10.10.10.10
  username: admincreds
  password: password
  database: database
  sslca/sslkey/sslcert: false
```

But I'm still getting the SSL error I expect:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1) (Mysql2::Error)
```

Is there a different parameter I can put in that can skip over or not use ssl in database.yml or elsewhere? I just need to run a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

According to `mysql2` documentation you should set,

```
secure_auth: false
```

when using yaml conf for ActiveRecord connection.

Comment: I tried adding that in to the yaml conf and it didn't work. :(

Still getting the same SSL error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options) points out:

```
ssl_mode: disabled
```

Worked for me.